# "Небыло" или "не было"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Как правильно писать: "небыло" или "не было"?

Answer (score 13):

*НЕ* с глаголами пишется раздельно. Нужно писать "*не было*" (варианты слитного написания, когда без *НЕ* глагол не употребляется, к этому случаю отношения не имеют).

Answer (score 1):

[[БЫТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)], ***наст. вр. нет (кроме 3 л. ед.***: есть; *книжн.*, ***3 л. мн.***: суть); будь, бу́дьте; был, была́, **бы́ло** (*с отриц.*: не́ был, не была́, **не́ было**, не́ были); бу́ду, бу́дешь; бы́вший; бу́дучи; ***нсв.*** — это глагол.

Одно из главных орфографических правил гласит: ***не*** с глаголами пишется раздельно.

Исключение составляют слова, которые без «не» не употребляются:
негодовать, недоумевать, нездоровиться, неволить, неймётся, ненавидеть, невзлюбить, неистовствовать, несдобровать, невзвидеть (света).

***Не было*** бы счастья, да несчастье помогло (пословица).

***Не было*** гвоздя — подкова пропала.
**Не было** подковы — лошадь захромала.
Лошадь захромала — командир убит.
Конница разбита — армия бежит.
Враг вступает в город, пленных не щадя,
Оттого что в кузнице **не было** гвоздя.
Перевод с английского С. Я. Маршака

[«Не» с глаголами](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/ne-s-glagolami.html)