# «Оттого(,) что в кузнице не было гвоздя». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, авторская-пунктуация

"Гвоздь и подкова", английская народная баллада (перевод С. Я. Маршака).

> Не было гвоздя — подкова пропала.
>   Не было подковы — лошадь захромала.
>   Лошадь захромала — командир убит.
>   Конница разбита — армия бежит.
>   Враг вступает в город, пленных не щадя,
>   Оттого, что в кузнице не было гвоздя.

При ответе на давнишний вопрос ([“Небыло” или “не было”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE)) в качестве примера привела это стихотворение и обнаружила, что [в некоторых](http://www.ollelukoe.ru/marsac/marsacgwozdypodcowa) источниках запятая в указанном месте стоит, [в некоторых](https://books.google.ee/books?id=nsZInZV7SEUC&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437&dq=%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4,%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8F,%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F.&source=bl&ots=duBDHHm0sD&sig=ACfU3U01CCmVbFRuTdS3ZmmbOj-7LCfkCA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij2bXL6IXpAhVExosKHeUwADI4FBDoATAIegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F.&f=false) — нет (есть и другие [пунктуационные вариации](http://staroeradio.ru/audio/19680)).
Подскажите, нужна ли запятая в обозначенном месте?
Как бы вы пунктуационно оформили эту балладу?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае выбор остаётся за автором. Моё мнение: по сюжету баллады я бы сделал логическое ударение на первой части союза (**оттого**), следовательно, нужна запятая перед **что**. Что касается авторского выбора, я бы ориентировался на [собрания сочинений](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UY1gAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&dq=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPsbPaiYbpAhVIpYsKHakzACYQ6AEIJzAA) советских времён, а не на современные пересказы без указания источника.

**Дополнение**.
Несколько ссылок, чтобы увидеть полный текст: [начало](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UY1gAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&dq=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz64Pyw4bpAhWjtYsKHeCHC9EQ6AEIJzAA), [продолжение](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UY1gAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&dq=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-mpWHxIbpAhXPxIsKHVTZB28Q6AEIJzAA), [продолжение](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UY1gAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%22&dq=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%22%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_2-fPw4bpAhVFlosKHXCRAGEQ6AEILzAB).

Comment: Спасибо, Медведик (извините, если сочтете за фамильярность). А есть ли возможность посмотреть в собрании всю балладу? Я попыталась выцарапать — не получилось. Подмогните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова (Римма, на Вас не обижусь в любом случае :) В отфотографированном виде я это издание найти не смог. В оцифрованном этот том можно посмотреть [здесь](http://flibusta.is/b/341304/read) (саму балладу несложно найти поиском на этой странице). Хотя, конечно, скан-копия была бы надёжнее.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Но такую странную пунктуацию — как в ссылке — никак нельзя считать ни правильной, ни даже авторской. _Не было гвоздя
Подкова
Пропала.
Не было подковы
Лошадь
Захромала.
Лошадь захромала
Командир
Убит.
Конница разбита —
Армия
Бежит.
Враг вступает в город,
Пленных не щадя,
Оттого, что в кузнице
Не было гвоздя._ Какие-то "препинательные" знаки ведь должны быть. Странно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Вот в том-то и дело. А потом другие цитируют из таких вот "источников". Я попытался по кусочкам собрать это в оригинале. Вроде, получилось. Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, нахожусь в связи с карантином на даче, вдали от своих книг… И потому могу привести фото только с одного доступного мне сейчас издания — 1987 года:

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Римма Михайлова:

> Как бы вы пунктуационно оформили эту балладу?

Так же, как и составители приведённого мною издания.

Comment: Ага! Спасибо-спасибо, Слава. Вы считаете, что на месте четвертого тире должна быть запятая, а отмеченная запятая не нужна. Интересуюсь — а почему?

Comment: А может, написал бы так:

Лощадь захромала —
Командир
Убит, (запятая)

Конница разбита,
Армия
Бежит… (многоточие)

Враг вступает в город,
Пленных не щадя, — (запятая + тире)

Оттого что в кузнице
Не было гвоздя. 

(В конце вместо точки мог бы поставить и восклицательный знак.)