# Деепричастный оборот внутри обособленного придаточного предложения. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, деепричастный-оборот

Нужна ли указанная запятая в предложении?

> Сундук находится в пещере, попасть в которую можно(,) только изучив карту.

Comment: Что означает "перед формулировкой деепричастием, стоящим внутри подчинённой части"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Из Розенталя**:

> § 20. <...> Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы
> ***только, лишь,*** интонационно не отделяется от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), но запятая перед
> ним **обычно ставится**: *Понять это произведение **можно, только**
> учитывая условия его создания; Выучить иностранный язык **можно,
> лишь** постоянно занимаясь им.*
>
> Но (при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым): *Они встретились только
> будучи уже взрослыми.*
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Comment: Так и не могу понять, нужно ставить запятую или нет?   Вы не могли бы в начале ответа приводить правильно оформленное предложение?  По правилу запятая не ставится при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым. А как в данном случае, сливаются ли они или нет?

Answer (score 2):

**Улучшаем качество ответа, делаем наш форум еще лучше**

**Замечания по предыдущему ответу:**

(1) Не приводится пример **правильного оформления** предложения.

(2) Цитируется правило Розенталя с двумя вариантами, но выбор нужного варианта **не указывается.**

(3) **Неточно определена тема вопроса**, так как ответ связывается с частицей «только».  Но в заданном вопросе этой темы нет, там указана другая тема (деепричастный оборот внутри обособленного придаточного).  К тому же частица не является определяющим фактором при выборе знака.

**Ответ на вопрос**

Предлагаемое **редактирование** названия вопроса: «Нужна ли запятая перед  деепричастным оборотом, находящимся  внутри обособленного придаточного предложения?»

В приведенном предложении оборот **обособляется**, причем к обороту примыкает частица «только», которая входит в его состав: *Сундук находится в пещере, **попасть в которую можно, только изучив карту.***

**Пояснение**

1. Деепричастный оборот внутри другой обособленной конструкции  (придаточного предложения, причастного или другого деепричастного оборота) **может и не обособляться, если он тесно примыкает** к сказуемому, причастию или деепричастию.  Это возможно в тех случаях, если оборот играет роль **обстоятельства образа действия**.

Розенталь в своих правилах приводит такие примеры: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113  Примечание, пункт 1.

Деепричастный оборот не отделяется запятой от причастия или другого деепричастия, к которому тесно примыкает:

*Кучер, **спавший опершись на локоть**, начал пятить лошадей.
Даже и Ласка, **спавшая свернувшись кольцом в краю сена**, неохотно встала.
Но Клим видел, что Лида, **слушая рассказы отца поджав губы**, не верит им.
Соня, **слушавшая его едва переводя дыхание,** вдруг схватила мантильку, шляпку и выбежала из комнаты.*

2. В приведенном предложении деепричастный оборот имеет значение **обстоятельства условия** (если изучить карту) и **поэтому обособляется** (тесного примыкания оборота к сказуемому в этом случае нет).

Приведем для сравнения пример, в котором оборот является обстоятельством образа действия , примыкает к сказуемому и не обособляется: *Это была очень маленькая пещера, **спать в которой можно только свернувшись  калачиком**.*

3. **Наличие частиц** «только», «лишь»  не влияет на обособление оборота.  В правилах Розенталя приводятся оба варианта (с обособлением оборота и без обособления), при этом в обоих случаях перед оборотом находится частица «только».
   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113, пункт 3.

*Понять это произведение можно, **только** учитывая условия его создания.*  Но (при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым): *Они встретились **только** будучи уже взрослыми.*

Comment: Ни одного голоса, ни одного комментария и полное торжество частицы "только" – малой толики – над всем, что границ не имеет. Надо бы удалить пост, да жаль, он мне много чего рассказал, а смысл примерно такой: Нам толико столько, а больше не нужно. Иди-ка ты лесом.

Comment: Ну зачем Вы так? Достойный, качественный ведь ответ — со ссылками, с примерами, с разбором нюансов.

Comment: Ну как же — _не принято говорить людям что-то хорошее и доброе_? Очень даже принято. Я так делаю. И Артём, и Иван Ольшанский, и Саша-Стрелец, и Alex_ander, и Серж, и Медведик — многие.

Comment: Прежде чем покуситься на чье-то личное пространство (во избежание негативной реакции), я **всегда** спрашиваю. У _grizzly_ (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460455/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/460462?noredirect=1#comment473979_460462), у Артёма (Лугового), у Александра (Стрельца), у Галины (Аванесовой), у Славы (slava1947)... И я рада, что пока не ошибалась с выбором обращения.

Comment: Спасибо за улыбку, Римма! Мне нравится обращение Саша, и с дефисом хорошо!

Comment: Извините меня,  дорогие участники форума, теперь я вижу, какие вы все милые и добрые, как хорошо относитесь друг к другу. Я сожалею, что этой атмосферы не чувствуется в нашей постоянной работе, и я почему-то часто вижу там ревность, обиду, замкнутость, не говоря уж обо всем прочем – куда только деваются эти островки доброты, почему появляются так редко.  Иногда  я даже заглядываю в прошлый форум (2012 года)   – тогда, как мне кажется,  он был  много лучше и добрее. Но, увы, я то время уже не застала, а мне жесткая конкуренция досталась почти сразу, причем по полной программе.

Comment: Где же были все милые и добрые люди? Да рядом они были,  просто молчали.  Впрочем, молчат и сейчас, удобная позиция… Тогда стихи давайте, что ли, почитаем: «…Нас заела речей маята. Но под всеми словесными перлами  Проступает пятном немота. Пусть другие кричат от отчаянья,  От обиды, от боли, от голода! Мы-то знаем – доходней молчание, Потому что молчание – золото!»